# How can I connect iphone library with my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to doing a project where i need to connect to iphone music library. When my application is start music file is add my application and play when i want.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with the current version of the SDK.

Comment: It is possible with version 3.0 of the SDK, though.

Answer (score 0):

You will have read only access to the iPhone / iPod Touch media library in the 3.0 SDK. I.e. you will be able to play songs, but not modify anything.